# Vector editor Adobe Flash CC alternatives

Tags: flash, vector-graphics, flash-cc

I'm looking some vector editing tool which can allow me do next drawing:

https://youtu.be/nbyqhru41co

*(I made this sketch in 2 minutes with Adobe Flash CC)*

Requirements:

- Auto snapping - cursor is snapped to line ending or segment center;
- Easy select part of object - select side of square with one click, select big object with double click, select everything in rectangle selection;
- Auto detect lines intersection;
- Layers support.

Optional requirements:

- OS Windows;
- Free or OpenSource.

I've tried [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) but it's hard to use. Can't find how to select part of square, how to detect lines intersection. Can't understand object and path concepts and why do I need to convert one to another?

Comment: Is there nothing available [from research](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=alternative+to+flash+animate) that you want?

Comment: I search for alternatives and tried a lot: Inkscape, Synfig Studio, Lunacy, Gravit Designer, etc.

Simple test: draw a square and try to remove one of its sides. It's surprising hard to do in all editors except Adobe Flash.